# How to stream video from VLC with subtitles overlayed?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, subtitles

I am trying to stream a video with VLC with subtitles overlayed on my local network.

The command I am using without success:

```
vlc -vvv myvideo.mkv :sub-file=mysub.srt :file-caching=300 ":sout=#transcode{vcode=h264,vb=800,scale=Auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=dvbs,soverlay}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/}" :sout-keep
```

When I connect from a vlc/mpv client I have option to enable subtitles that actually doesn't show anything.

PS: Setting up the stream from the GUI wizard works most of the time and give me this exactly same code. The video runs with those subtitles locally without problems. I also tried with many different videos with different containers(avi, mkv, mp4, flv).